# Cannot export RSA parameters with RsaCryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I'm trying to export the modulus of RSA key and get strange result.

First I was generated 3072 RSA key pair on "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider"

Now I want to export the parameters, when I use Cng I got the correct result

```
RSACng Cng = new RSACng(CngKey.Open("RSA3072KEY") new CngProvider("Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider")) 

Console.WriteLine(cng.ExportParameters(false).Modulus.Length)
```

The output is 384.

But when I use RsaCryptoServiceProvider I got wrong result.

```
CspParameters parameters = new CspParameter() { KeyContainerName = "RSA3072KEY", ProviderName = "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider", ProviderType = 1};

using(RSACryptoServiceProvider key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(parameter)
{  
 Console.WriteLine(key.ExportParameters(false).Modulus.Length) 
}
```

The output is 128

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: Can you please explain exactly where to look

Comment: Look at the provider in first paragraph.